# Computabillity of packing of spheres with different radii

Tags: algorithms, computability-theory

This is a conceptually easier version of a box packing problem I stated [earlier](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330023/box-stacking-problem).

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $r_1, \ldots, r_n$ be positive integers. We take $r_i$ to be the radius of a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for each $i\in \{1,\ldots, n\}$.

Let $R$ be the minimum positive integer such that we can pack all the small spheres into one big sphere of radius $R$.

Is the problem of finding $R$ given $n$ and the radii $\{r_i:i\in\{1,\ldots, n\}\}$ of the small spheres, computable?

Comment: In practice, I think it is. Once you have packed n-1 spheres in a minimal radius enclosure, there are only finitely many interesting ways to add an nth sphere while attempting to minimize the radius. If you can place it inside the enclosure, there are only finitely many other spheres it can touch, and when it touches at least three other spheres, this can be done at most two ways. So there are only finitely many interesting configurations to check.  Gerhard "Hoping That Uninteresting Doesn't Matter" Paseman, 2019.04.28.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is computable.  Use the decidability of the theory of the real numbers $(\mathbb{R}, 0, 1, \times, +, <)$.  With a very little standard work, you can define $\mathbb{R}^3$, vector addition, and the norm function $|x|$. Then using the decidability of real-closed fields search for the minimum $R \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the following is true:
$$ \exists x_0, ..., x_n \in \mathbb{R}^3 \left(\bigwedge_{i \neq j} |x_i - x_j| \geq r_i + r_j \quad \land\quad \bigwedge_{i}|x_i| + r_i \leq R\right) $$
This search will terminate before $R > r_1 + ... + r_n$.

---

If you relax it to reals, then it is also computable.  First, we can fit the balls within a large sphere of center the origin and radius $R' = r_1 + ... + r_n$ by lining the balls in a line.

Then you can use compactness.  The function $R(x_1, ..., x_n) = \min_i (|x_i| + r_i)$ is computable and it describes the minimal radius $R$ which fits all the balls if they have center $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$.  Now the desired value $R$ is equal to $\inf_{x_1, ..., x_n} R(x_1, ..., x_n)$ where the minimum is over all $x_i, x_j$ such that $|x_i| \leq R'$ and $|x_i - x_j| \geq r_i + r_j$.  Classically, this this is an infimum over a continuous function on a compact domain so it is realized.  Computably, this minimum is also computable since it is the minimum of a computable function whose domain is what is called a "computable subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$" in the computable analysis literature.

Comment: Excellent explanation - thanks Jason!